# PyObjc error while trying to deploy flask app on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, pyobjc

I am trying to deploy my first web app on Heroku however I am getting a PyObjc error while pushing the code. I am doing this on a Mac Machine. This predictive application is developed using Flask.
I do not know why this error is occurring as I do not have the PyObjc in my requirements.txt

```
alabaster==0.7.12
appdirs==1.4.4
applaunchservices==0.2.1
appnope==0.1.2
argon2-cffi==20.1.0
arrow==0.13.1
astroid==2.6.6
async-generator==1.10
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==21.4.0
Babel==2.9.1
backcall==0.2.0
binaryornot==0.4.4
black==19.10b0
bleach==4.1.0
brotlipy==0.7.0
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
chardet==4.0.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
click==8.0.3
cloudpickle==2.0.0
colorama==0.4.4
cryptography==36.0.0
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.5.1
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
diff-match-patch==20200713
docutils==0.17.1
entrypoints==0.3
flake8==3.9.2
Flask==2.0.2
fonttools==4.29.1
idna==3.3
imagesize==1.3.0
importlib-metadata==4.8.2
inflection==0.5.1
intervaltree==3.1.0
ipykernel==6.4.1
ipython==7.31.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort==5.9.3
itsdangerous==2.0.1
jedi==0.18.1
Jinja2
jinja2-time==0.2.0
joblib==1.1.0
jsonify==0.5
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter-client==6.1.12
jupyter-core==4.9.1
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
keyring==23.4.0
kiwisolver==1.3.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0
MarkupSafe
matplotlib==3.5.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.2
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.4
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
nbclient==0.5.3
nbconvert==6.3.0
nbformat==5.1.3
nest-asyncio==1.5.1
notebook==6.4.6
numpy==1.22.2
numpydoc==1.2
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.4.0
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
pathspec==0.7.0
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==9.0.1
pip==21.2.4
pluggy==1.0.0
poyo==0.5.0
prometheus-client==0.13.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.20
psutil==5.8.0
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pycparser==2.21
pydocstyle==6.1.1
pyflakes==2.3.1
Pygments==2.10.0
pylint==2.9.6
pyls-spyder==0.4.0
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.4
pyrsistent==0.18.0
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-lsp-black==1.0.0
python-lsp-jsonrpc==1.0.0
python-lsp-server==1.2.4
python-slugify==5.0.2
pytz==2021.3
PyYAML==6.0
pyzmq==22.3.0
QDarkStyle==3.0.2
qstylizer==0.1.10
QtAwesome==1.0.3
qtconsole
QtPy==1.11.2
regex==2021.11.2
requests==2.27.1
rope==0.22.0
Rtree==0.9.7
scikit-learn==1.0.2
scipy==1.7.3
seaborn==0.11.2
Send2Trash==1.8.0
setuptools==58.0.4
six==1.16.0
sklearn==0.0
snowballstemmer==2.2.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
Sphinx==4.4.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.5
spyder==5.1.5
spyder-kernels==2.1.3
terminado==0.9.4
testpath==0.5.0
text-unidecode==1.3
textdistance==4.2.1
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
three-merge==0.1.1
tinycss==0.4
tornado==6.1
traitlets==5.1.1
typed-ast==1.4.3
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
ujson==4.2.0
Unidecode==1.2.0
urllib3==1.26.8
watchdog==2.1.6
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==2.0.2
wheel==0.37.1
whichcraft==0.6.1
wrapt==1.12.1
wurlitzer==3.0.2
xgboost==1.5.2
yapf==0.31.0
zipp==3.7.0
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 ERROR: Cannot install applaunchservices because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
       
       The conflict is caused by:
           pyobjc 8.2 depends on pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==8.2
           pyobjc 8.1 depends on pyobjc-framework-CoreData==8.1
           pyobjc 8.0 depends on pyobjc-framework-CoreAudio==8.0
           pyobjc 7.3 depends on pyobjc-core==7.3
           pyobjc 7.2 depends on pyobjc-framework-CoreAudioKit==7.2
           pyobjc 7.1 depends on pyobjc-framework-CoreMIDI==7.1
           pyobjc 7.0.1 depends on pyobjc-framework-CoreAudioKit==7.0.1
           pyobjc 7.0 depends on pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==7.0
           pyobjc 6.2.2 depends on pyobjc-core==6.2.2
           pyobjc 6.2.1 depends on pyobjc-framework-CoreServices==6.2.1
           pyobjc 6.2 depends on pyobjc-framework-Security==6.2
           pyobjc 6.1 depends on pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==6.1
           pyobjc 6.0.1 depends on pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==6.0.1
           pyobjc 6.0 depends on pyobjc-framework-Security==6.0
           pyobjc 5.3 depends on pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==5.3
           pyobjc 5.2 depends on pyobjc-core==5.2
           pyobjc 5.1.2 depends on pyobjc-framework-CoreAudio==5.1.2
           pyobjc 5.1.1 depends on pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==5.1.1
           pyobjc 5.1 depends on pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==5.1
           pyobjc 5.0 depends on pyobjc-framework-WebKit==5.0
           pyobjc 4.2.2 depends on pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==4.2.2
           pyobjc 4.2.1 depends on pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==4.2.1
           pyobjc 4.2 depends on pyobjc-framework-CoreText==4.2
           pyobjc 4.1 depends on pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==4.1
       
       To fix this you could try to:
       1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
       2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
       
       ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`applaunchservices`](https://pypi.org/project/applaunchservices/) appears to be Apple-only:

> Simple package for registering an app with apple Launch Services to handle UTI and URL. See Apple documentations for details.

I suspect you don't need that, either. Did you create your `requirements.txt` from a `pip freeze`? There's likely a *bunch* of stuff in there you don't need.

I suggest you review that file and remove anything you aren't directly depending on. `pip` will find transitive dependencies (dependencies your dependencies depend on) and install them automatically.

Prune that file, commit, and redeploy.

Comment: I am using a virtual environment and used pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. That outputs everything installed in the current Python environment, which apparently includes things you don't actually need. "Is there any other way to do that?"—sure: just write the file. If you need click, add it to your requirements file manually then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. That way only the things you actually need are listed in that file.

Comment: Basically, flip it around: Don't install stuff then generate your requirements from the environment. Define your requirements, then build an environment from those requirements.

Comment: I changed the requirements.txt as you suggested and it got through the deployment phase but the application crashed with an error code=H10. I am just hoping this has nothing to do with the changes in the requirements.txt

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Chris